# Determine the number of affected rows by an update_recordset call in Dynamics 4.0?

Tags: x++, axapta, ax

I have an `update_recordset` call in my code, and I'd like to echo back the number of rows that were affected by this update. In version 2009 and 2012, there's a `RowCount()` function I can call.

How can I accomplish this in Dynamics 4.0?

I do not want to change this to a `select forupdate` call, due to the performance hit.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems to be no other solution in 4.0, apart of doing a `select count(RecId)...` before the update and in the same transaction.

RowCount() functionality was implemented on later versions and there is no way to recover that information of the corresponding command launched to SQL Server.

Best regards

Comment: This is the conclusion I was coming to as well, but good to hear it from a second source. Thanks!